# Handle mouse click on a gameobject - Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, onmouseclick

I have a small city mesh and an apartment 3d model. I add the mesh to my scene and place the 3d model on the mesh.

I try to handle mouse click only on 3d model. I use below code. But  I click anywhere on the screen, it sets as sound = true

I add a mesh collider to 3d model gameobject.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Plane p = new Plane (Camera.main.transform.forward , transform.position);
            Ray r = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            float d;
            if(p.Raycast (r, out d)) {
                sound = true;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check tag/name of game object. you need to use like that:

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

        Plane p = new Plane (Camera.main.transform.forward , transform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100)) 
        {
            //Choose one of them below!!!

            /// Name Comparison
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.equals("NameOfTheObject")){
               ///Do Logic
            }

            //Tag Comparison
            if(hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("TagOfTheObject")){
                ///Do Logic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do same task using Plane.Raycast? It doesn't requires any collider. And it doesn't consists a hit.

Comment: @zumma judging from your code its seems you are creating a plane that you are always hitting. Try changing the plane values

Comment: @zumma what is d value? Please write Debug.Log(d); after if statement.

Comment: @BarışÇırıka values are 34, 110, 199 when I click on different parts of  the 3d model. It has a wide range.

Comment: It checks if ray intersects your plane. So it intersects and distances are 34,110,199. I think compare hit is good way. Because when you clicked mouse it raycasts so not much performance problems.